# Gathering strings from a website that starts refusing your connection after a certain amount of time

Tags: java

I am currently creating a program that, based on constantly changing variables, connects to a website, and gathers information. It must connect to the website up to 400 times. The subject website seems to display a blank screen after a certain amount of connections, about 10-30. Does anyone know the best way find how long to wait between connections?

```
 public static String pullString(int id) {

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I would leave out the URL in the sample code.  I'm pretty sure it breaks the terms of usage for this site, and almost all others, to request the website using a program.

Comment: There is no way to easily discover how many requests in what period of time will result in a website from blocking your connections. An alternative option (in this case) is to create your own website which runs every time the game's price database updates, and then to crawl your own website for the data.  Another option is to use a site which indirectly provides this for you, such as [tip.it](http://www.tip.it/).

Comment: Although that would usually work, but I am not trying to get the prices, I am trying to get a less stored value, Type:, Unfortunately i have not been able to find other website that store this data.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a security feature built into the providers web servers to prevent DOS attacks... One way to circumvent is use a proxy connection after you start receiving "blank screens".

Comment: In that case, the best choice would be to store or cache all of the types, since they are constants.

Comment: The website blocks from 10-30, each needs 400,and hundreds of these would be running at the same time. So conventional proxy methods won't be applicable.

Comment: Unfortunatly, as you can see here from this outdated item list http://pastebin.com/dcWVaWYU , There are quite a few items. Too many to be stored in normal arrays, or array list formats. Text documents cannot be used.

Comment: You won't be able to acquire all of the types in one go, of course.  Not all items in that list are on the database of tradable items anyway, so it won't be more than a few thousand requests that you could spread out over a period of time.

Comment: Would you just suggest I store them in an array?

Comment: Yes, but you should store them in a text file so that you can easily reread them between application executions (as an array won't persist between runs, and an array of constants is overly messy)

Comment: Unfortunately the platform I use disabled the access of local files. Now that I think about it, I could make a pastebin, take the raw url, then grab the Array from the website all in one go.

Comment: I seee you have worked on this problem before.
 Anyway, here's mine; one connection loads ALL data for an item, and it does so using RuneScape's Grand Exchange API.

Comment: Uploading that text file to pastebin and then caching it locally would be your best option.  I assume that platform you speak of is RSBot?  If so, let's discuss there rather than in comments here.  My username there is the same as my username here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get there from work, but google `runescape api`. They have one [here](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Grand_Exchange_APIs), and I'll bet they expect you to use it.

Comment: That's what I am using, which refuses connections.

Comment: Oh. Well, I'd look for a FAQ or email them and ask them what the problem is.

Comment: Well seeing as what I am doing isn't exactly sponsored by jagex, I don't think they will help.

Answer (score 0):

Once it starts blocking you, does it eventually let you reconnect? You might be able to do some sort of algorithm to dynamically find how fast to try again.

You could consider something similar to what TCP congestion control does: start with some wait time between connections. When one completes successfully, decrease the wait time by a constant. When you get an error, double the wait time (or multiply by a constant).

It's very likely, though, that they're doing something more complicated than just rate-limiting connections. Without knowing what you have to get around, it's hard to know how to get around it.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, it seemed like each reconnect time is different. Quite unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

If the website is giving you random block time after you reach certain limit it's almost impossible to find the best wait time. I think your best bet is to use a pool of http proxy to access the website in round robin way. Though that's not very nice... But technically it should be the best way to access a website programmatically if it blocks you after a certain amount of traffic.

Here is a link about how to use proxy: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

You can also use HttpClient which is simpler.

Try to google around and you can find a lot of free proxy server list.